# Making a specific pattern in Java

Tags: java

How do I make this pattern using a input from the user?
input=3

(1st line)+
(2nd line)--
(third line)+++

I have tried using the for loops but just couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, what is the input? 
What is the expected output? 
What is the actual output?

Comment: input = number from user and output = +(first line),--(second line),+++(3rd line),----(fourth line)..etc

Comment: Could you, please, include some examples?

Answer (score 0):

First, we can judge the parity of a value by taking the remainder of 2

```
    get the input value;
    loop i = 1 & i <= input value:
       when i is odd output char is "+" 
       when i is even  output char is "-" 
       loop j = 0 & j < i
            print i times output char
```

code：

```
    int inputVal = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i <= inputVal; i++) {
        String outputTag = i % 2 == 0 ? "-" : "+";
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(outputTag);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Input");

        int input = inp.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            String symbol = i%2 == 0 ? '-' : '+';
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(symbol);
            }

            System.out.print("line" + (i+1) + "\t");
        }
```